# Show angular Material progress-bar And disable all contents of the page until page loads

Tags: progress-bar, angular-material, angular5

I have created a form in mat-card using angular material and added Indeterminate progress-bar to the mat-card.When submitting the form How to disable the mat-card until the progress-bar is loading?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show angular-loading-bar And disable all contents of the page until page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012705/show-angular-loading-bar-and-disable-all-contents-of-the-page-until-page-loads)

Comment: not duplicate as framework versions are different i.e Angular 5 vs Angular JS 1